# Why won't my video background appear even though code seems right?

Tags: html, css, laravel, debugging

I'm making a Laravel application and on my auth page, I want there to be a video background that keeps playing.  The file path is correct in the `<source/>` tag but I'm not sure what's causing it not to appear?  I'm guessing it's the CSS but I could be wrong.  Below's my code.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my `app.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">

        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
            <source src="nyc_vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>

        <div class="content">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi pro.</p>
            <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
        </div>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="items navbar-nav mx-auto">
                        @include('partials.rules')
                        @include('partials.about')
                        @include('partials.faq')
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>



                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>


                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    <script>
        var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        function myFunction() {
            if (video.paused) {
                video.play();
                btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
            } else {
                video.pause();
                btn.innerHTML = "Play";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my `app.scss`:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Hi @luvs2spuge , I think here source path is a problem. Can you tell me where you store the images in your folder which are display in a webpage? is it in the public/ images folder?

Answer (score 1):

you should use the asset() method to video src

```
<source src="{{ asset('nyc_vid.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
```